# What's the difference between these two approaches to class initialization?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android. Can someone explain the difference between these two approaches to class initialization?

```
jamba = new JambaApplication(); 
jamba = (JambaApplication)  getApplication();
```

Answer (score 3):

One creates a new instance of Jamba Application and assigns it to Jamba (= new JambaApplication()),

And one gets the current application (or whatever getApplication() returns) and casts it to a JambaApplication (which may throw casting errors), and assigns it to Jamba.

You should study some java though since this is basic java.